# Docker run stuck with WSL 2 and latest GPU driver

Tags: docker, cuda, wsl-2, nvidia-docker

I am trying to run a docker container on Windows with GPU support. The container is stuck at run with no output/logs. It is not even responding to kill or rm.

Hardware

- OS: Windows x86 amd64
- GPU: RTX 3060 Ampere architecture

Following https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html

1. CUDA Version: 12.1
2. CUDA Toolkit in WSL2: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_local
3. Docker latest version with WSL2 backend

[docker run output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGKSx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with [Docker Desktop 4.17.0](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13324)